# How to set web.xml to org.apache.tomee.embedded.Configuration

Tags: web.xml, apache-tomee

The essence of the problem: how to transfer your own *web.xml* file to

`new org.apache.tomee.embedded.Configuration().setWebXml("file_name")`.

When I set http port as `new org.apache.tomee.embedded.Configuration().setHttpPort(_port)` works fine.

But, when set `web.xml` it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think `setWebXml` is a dead config but you can `setConf("/folder/in/resources")` and put a `web.xml` in this folder. It will put it in conf folder and do what you want